# AlertDialog is not showing in other activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

**Function:**

Alert dialog method was created to notify user on the status of the account, hence, the dialog will pop-up when the user has been logged out remotely. Furthermore, there are 4 activities within the app; hence, when the account is logged, the dialog will pop-up when the user decides to navigate to the next activity. The dialog pop-up will then navigate the user back to the login page when it has been acknowledged.

**Issue:**

Alert Dialog doesn't pop up when the user account has been logged out, logout bttn has been changed to login and sharedpreference credentials have been cleared. It still allows the user to navigate around the app, the app will be displayed after a delayed period.

What has gone wrong with the codes and any suggestions?

**Code**

```
//Build an AlertDialog to notify user on Session Logout status
static Builder alertDialog(final Activity act,final Intent yourintent){
    Log.i("RootActivity:alertDialog","******Session Logout Info******");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Sign In For Spacetobe Services");
    alertDialog.setMessage("For security reasons, you have been automatically logged out after 20 minutes of inactivity." +
            "To access Spacetobe services, please sign in again.");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    //SETTING OF OK BUTTON
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Intent yourintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //yourintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            act.startActivity(yourintent);//Return page to PROPERTYACTIVITY
            }
   }); return alertDialog;
}

//LOGOUT METHOD & CLEARING OF SHARED PREFERENCE CREDENTIALS
public void IdleLogout(){
    Log.i("RootActivity:IdleLogout()","******APP LOGGEDOUT******");

    //SharedPreference method cleared
    Log.i("RootActivity:IdleLogout()","******loginButton is set******");
    setloginButton();   // Change logout button to login
    checkTimeout=true; // Global timeout is true
 //RootActivity.alertDialog(this,getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)).create().show();
}

//EDITED VERSION TO GET LOGOUT DIALOG WHEN USER TRIES TO NAVIGATE TO OTHER ACTIVITY BY BACK BTTN WHEN LOGGED OUT
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    Log.i("RootActivity:onBackPreseed()","******Back bttn has been selected******");

    if (checkTimeout==true){
        Log.i("RootActivity:onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)","******Timeout=true******");
        RootActivity.alertDialog(this,getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)).create().show();
        checkTimeout = false;
    }return;
}
//END OF EDITED VERSION TO GET LOGOUT DIALOG WHEN USER TRIES TO NAVIGATE TO OTHER ACTIVITY BY BACK BTTN WHEN LOGGED OUT

// For each new individual activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;

    //EDITED VERSION TO GET START TIME FOR EACH USER INTERACTION WITH THE ACTIVITY
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.i("RootActivity:onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)","******startTime=******"+startTime);
    //END OF EDITED VERSION TO GET START TIME FOR EACH USER INTERACTION WITH THE ACTIVITY

    //EDITED VERSION TO GET LOGOUT DIALOG WHEN USER TRIES TO NAVIGATE TO OTHER ACTIVITY WHEN LOGGED OUT
    if (checkTimeout==true){
        Log.i("RootActivity:onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)","******Timeout=true******");
        RootActivity.alertDialog(this,getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)).create().show();
        checkTimeout = false;
    }return;
    //END OF EDITED VERSION TO GET LOGOUT DIALOG WHEN USER TRIES TO NAVIGATE TO OTHER ACTIVITY WHEN LOGGED OUT
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the dialog code to onResume() method, at that time, activity is visible.